# hadoop replication not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i have made a cluster of 3 servers for hadoop.
the problem that i am facing is that my data and output both are being replicated at all the nodes even if the replication factor is 1.i have tried replication factor 1 ,2 and 3 , all of them give me the same result.
i believe my replication property is not working properly.
here is the property that i used :

```
<property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
          <value>1</value>
</property>
```

please suggest what should i do

Comment: As Lashane says, in which file did you set this property? Did you restart hadoop?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check whether this value actually in hdfs-site.xml
2. Restart name node and data nodes
3. Use [setrep](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#setrep) command to set replication factor of existing files
4. Run [balancer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#balancer)
5. Read rules of this site to avoid such questions in future

Comment: i set the property in hdfs file.I have restarted hadoop,used setrep and balancer as well but nothing seems to be working.... what should i do?

Comment: try to set `mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication` in `mapred-site.xml` to 1, btw, how do you see that blocks are replicated to all datanodes? what `fs fsck` reports about replication factor?